# undefined variable When loading the view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting this error of undefined variable in the `View` even though i have retrieved the data from table in the `doctorAppointment` model and then passed it to Controller and then controller passed it further to view.
This is the model

```
<?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class doctorAppointment extends Model
   {
      public function user()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
   }
```

this is my controller

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller

{
      public function GetAppointment()
      {
        $doctorAppointment= doctorAppointment::all();
        return view('dashboard',array('appointments'=>$doctorAppointment));
      }
  }
```

this is my view

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
  <p>{$appointment->patientEmail}</p>
@endforeach
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/dashboard',  'AppointmentController@GetAppointment');
```

Comment: i am using this statement in the controller to access model        use App\doctorAppointment

Comment: your class naming convention is wrong. First letter of Class name must be capital letter, which is `DoctorAppointment `. Do this in `GetAppointment` : `return view('dashboard')->with('appointments', $doctorAppointment);`

Comment: @Regolith corrected the naming convention as proposed but still not working   renamed the doctorAppointment as DoctorAppointment and renamed it in all other files as well

Comment: Can you try to dump the data in the controller to make sure there are data? Try use `dd($doctorAppointment);` after `$doctorAppointment = doctorAppointment::all();`. Because beside you are not following the convention, you have not define the table_name for laravel model. Another thing is you have to import the model file in controller header by type `use App\doctorAppointment;`

Comment: i imported the model in the controller i just forgot paste that statement.  i imported it as use App\DoctorAppointment

Comment: Can you tell more about the error? Because usually laravel error shows the line that cause the error.

Comment: can you post Table Structure.?

Comment: Please update the question to fix the errors to get more useful answers. The naming conventions etc shouldn't cause error on view. And are you sure that another part of the view is not causing the error? Because this code can throw a lot different errors but not `undefined variable` inside view...

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
public function GetAppointment()
{
   $doctorAppointment= doctorAppointment::all();
   return view('dashboard')->with('appointments', $doctorAppointment);
 }
```

Comment: it is still giving the same error even after trying changes you proposed above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think `<p>` tags value should be within double curly braces `{{ }}`.

```
<p>{{ $appointment->patientEmail }}</p>
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

And for undefined case try like:

```
<p>{{ $appointment->patientEmail or 'No Email'}}</p>
```

Comment: tried it with curly braces as well. still same error

Comment: `{{ print_r($appointments) }}` do this outside @foreach and check if any data is coming or not

Comment: did this but it is still giving undefined variable :/

Comment: Sorry, but one more try, can you please do a `dd($doctorAppointment)` in controller and check if data is coming from model?

Comment: i placed the dd($doctorAppointment) statement in the function of controller nothing is getting out on  the screen #sadlyf

Comment: ok. No problem. `dd($doctorAppointment->toArray())`, or you can serach if there is any key called `patientEmail`.

Comment: I guess your model might not be using the db table. try specifying the table name in model. `protected $table = "doctor_appointments";`

Comment: used that protected statement in the model as u mentioned above as well as did dd($doctorAppointment->toArray()) but nothing is coming out  but listen when i am doing like this in my view  {{$appointments->patientEmail or 'No Email'}}  no error is coming out but when i write like {{$appointments->patientEmail }}   again undefined crap came out :/

Comment: Then everything is fine till view. But there is now key as such `patientEmail` in the array. So you might check how many times its looping. if its 0 times then, array is not having any data. if in loop some are coming with actual email and some are as `No Email` then everythings right.

Comment: why don't you wrap @foreach with an `@if count($appointments) > 0`

Comment: should i put it in the @foreach()... @endforeach loop now ? right ?

Comment: @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                <p>{{$appointment->patientEmail or 'No Email'}}</p>
                @endforeach               did like this but still undefined :/

Comment: Nope. First check the length with `@if` then loop using `@foreach`. so place `@foreach` inside `@if`.

Comment: if(count($appointments)>0)
                @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                    <p>{{$appointment->patientEmail or 'No Email'}}</p>
                @endforeach
            endif

Comment: there is @ before if and before endif .

Comment: it is not getting the variable in the view even though the key controller is returning and key on which i am looping in view named as $appointments are same :/

Comment: And as you said, `{{ print_r($appointments) }}` is giving undefined means, No data is reaching to view. So you might have to recheck flow.

Comment: can you just check my model code in the initial question i posted ... just tell me whether its retrieving data from db or not ?

Comment: Whats your db table name?

Comment: 2017_07_24_044351_create_doctor_appointments_table.php     (doctor_appointments)

Comment: change the model's class name to `DoctorAppointment` and from controller call `DoctorAppointment::all()`.

Comment: patientEmail is in `user` table or `doctor_appointments` table? So you have to recheck flow. Can't help you with the sample you have given above for which all possible solutions are given by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code does this help

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller
{
  public function GetAppointment()
  {
    $appointments= doctorAppointment::all();
    return view('dashboard',compact('appointments'));
  }
}
```